# Lightning Experience slow loading issue

Tags: lightning-experience

I am simply logging into my SFDC Dev org and it takes me ages to load the content. The internet speed is above 4mbps but still the rainbow keeps showing. Following is the snapshot of network[image] performance where it shows long time for one.app:

This is so frustrating! This issue happens intermittently, but still happens a lot of times. Is there any case for this or any solution?

Comment: I also faced similar issue, we were creating tables using lightning component and for the complete table of about 400 entries to load it was taking around 12-18 seconds( 3 second is wait time for data to come to browser)

So instead of creating table using salesforce lightning component, I created using Datatable and table was loaded in 4 seconds( 3 second is wait time for data to come to browser)

While this is not the answer to your question, i am writing this to put in knowledge the sluggish nature of lightning component i faced